# Camel CXF Rest URL doesn't work

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I have camel blueprint and my service below I deployed my bundle in JBoss Fuse but when I tried to hit the URL I get pagenot found.

I can't understand the issue because I have deployed successfully what should be the rest URL in camel?

**http://localhost:8181/camelcxfrestservice/rest/customerservice/customers/123**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source
    Copyright 2014, Red Hat, Inc. and/or its affiliates, and individual
    contributors by the @authors tag. See the copyright.txt in the
    distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.

    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    You may obtain a copy of the License at
    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<!--
   This is the OSGi Blueprint XML file defining the Camel context and routes.  Because the file is in the
   OSGI-INF/blueprint directory inside our JAR, it will be automatically activated as soon as the bundle is installed.

   The root element for any OSGi Blueprint file is 'blueprint' - you also see the namespace definitions for both the Blueprint
   and the Camel namespaces.
-->
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0      https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd                                 http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint           http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd           http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd           http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">
    <!--
      The namespace for the camelContext element in Blueprint is 'https://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint'. Additionally,
      we can also define namespace prefixes we want to use them in the XPath expressions in our CBR.

      While it is not required to assign id's to the <camelContext/> and <route/> elements, it is a good idea
      to set those for runtime management purposes (logging, JMX MBeans, ...)
    -->
    <!-- Defined the real JAXRS back end service -->
    <jaxrs:server address="/rest" id="restService" staticSubresourceResolution="true">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="customerService"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>
    <!-- JAXRS providers -->
    <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider" id="jsonProvider"/>
    <bean class="CustomerService" id="customerService"/>
    <!-- Defined the server endpoint to create the cxf-rs consumer -->
    <cxf:rsServer address="/route" id="rsServer"
        loggingFeatureEnabled="true" loggingSizeLimit="20" serviceClass="CustomerService">
        <cxf:providers>
            <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
        </cxf:providers>
    </cxf:rsServer>
    <!-- Defined the client endpoint to create the cxf-rs producer -->
    <!--  <cxf:rsClient
        address="http://localhost:8181/CamelCXFRestService/rest"
        id="rsClient" loggingFeatureEnabled="true" serviceClass="CustomerService">
        <cxf:providers>
            <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
        </cxf:providers>
    </cxf:rsClient> -->
    <camelContext id="_context1" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="route1">
            <!-- Just need to ignoreDeleteMethodMessageBody -->
            <from id="_from1" uri="cxfrs://bean://rsServer"/>
            <to id="_to1" uri="log:body?level=INFO"/>
            <!--  <to id="_to2" uri="cxfrs://bean://rsClient?ignoreDeleteMethodMessageBody=true&amp;synchronous=true"/> -->
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

and my service

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/customerservice/")
public class CustomerService implements CustomerServiceResource{

    @Override
     @GET
        @Path("/customers/{id}/")
    public Customer getCustomer(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        Customer c = new Customer();
        c.setId(id);
        c.setName("Sarada");
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public Response updateCustomer(Customer customer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(String id, String payload) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check that your service is available in following address:

http://localhost:8181/cxf

If it is available, you must use following URL instead:

http://localhost:8181/cxf/rest/customerservice/customers/123